# NameError in code, 'mars' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting error for line 1 not sure what the problem is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'mars' is not defined
```

Here's the code:

```
x = int(input("what is the fourth planet in the solar system: "))
if x == mars:
    print ("correct")
else print ("incorrect")
```

Comment: still getting error message Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'mars'

Comment: Why the heck are you trying to `'mars'` to an integer?!

Comment: not really sure how to do it just started 2 weeks ago so I am very new at codeing

Comment: Why are you? `'mars'` isn't an integer!

Comment: what variables would work I have only used int and float

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the quotes around mars just like this `'mars'`